# Why will this not show MessageBox?

Tags: c#, messagebox

I am trying to write this program to tell the user if the name he entered is on the list of most popular names, for girls or boys. The problem I am having is that my button click wont display the message boxes that I have coded. I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I cant seem to get it to display.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadNames(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int size = 200;
        string[] names = new string[size];
        string[] names1 = new string[size];
        int index = 0;
        int index1 = 0;
        StreamReader inputfile1;
        StreamReader inputfile2;
        inputfile1 = File.OpenText(@"F:\C# HW\CH07_HW_07\BoysNames.txt");
        inputfile2 = File.OpenText(@"F:\C# HW\CH07_HW_07\GirlsNames.txt");
        while (!inputfile1.EndOfStream && index < names.Length)
        {
            names[index] = inputfile1.ReadLine();
            index++;
        }
        while (!inputfile2.EndOfStream && index1 < names1.Length)
        {
            names1[index1] = inputfile2.ReadLine();
            index1++;
        }
    }
    private Boolean FindBoyname()
    {
        const int size = 200;
        string[] BoyNames = new string[size];
        int index = 0;
        string boyname = textBox1.Text;
        Boolean Boyname = false;

        StreamReader inputfile1;
        inputfile1 = File.OpenText(@"F:\C# HW\CH07_HW_07\BoysNames.txt");
        while (!inputfile1.EndOfStream && index < BoyNames.Length)
        {
            BoyNames[index] = inputfile1.ReadLine();
            if (String.Equals(boyname, BoyNames[index], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                Boyname = true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return Boyname;
    }
    private Boolean FindGirlname()
    {
        const int size = 200;
        string[] GirlNames = new string[size];
        int index = 0;
        string girlname = textBox2.Text;
        Boolean Girlname = false;

        StreamReader inputfile1;
        inputfile1 = File.OpenText(@"F:\C# HW\CH07_HW_07\GirlsNames.txt");
        while (!inputfile1.EndOfStream && index < GirlNames.Length)
        {
            GirlNames[index] = inputfile1.ReadLine();
            if (String.Equals(girlname, GirlNames[index], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                Girlname = true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return Girlname;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean boy;
        Boolean girl;
        boy = FindBoyname();
        girl = FindGirlname();
        if (boy.Equals(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " is among the most popular boy names!");
        }
        if (boy.Equals(false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " is not among the most popular boy names.");
        }
        if (girl.Equals(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text + " is among the most popular girl names!");
        }
        if (girl.Equals(false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text + " is not among the most popular girl names.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  If you set a breakpoint in your `button1_Click` method, does the program ever hit it?

Comment: Try this: in the `Form1` constructor, add `button1.Click += button1_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `button1.Click` event is't subscribed with this `void button1_Click` event handler. Check it in design code or in the visual designer

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the code that has nothing to do with showing a message box you get:

I am trying to write this program to tell the user if the name he entered is on the list of most popular names, for girls or boys. The problem I am having is that my button click wont display the message boxes that I have coded. I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I cant seem to get it to display.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean boy;
        Boolean girl;
        if (boy.Equals(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " is among the most popular boy names!");
        }
        if (boy.Equals(false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " is not among the most popular boy names.");
        }
        if (girl.Equals(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text + " is among the most popular girl names!");
        }
        if (girl.Equals(false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text + " is not among the most popular girl names.");
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't wire up your event anywhere, so have a look inside `InitializeComponent` and see if it does so there.

You're looking for a line that reads:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

If it's not there, then that'll be why your code isn't showing anything.